# Importing command line not working on SSH Putty

Tags: mysql, ssh, command-line

I need to import my SQL file. So far this is what i have done:
1-created the database via SSH:

```
create database DB_name ;
```

2- Then i create the user:

```
create user 'USER_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'passw*****';
```

3- Grant permissions to the user:

```
GRANTS all privileges on DB_name.* TO 'USER_name'@'localhost';
```

4- Now i tried to import the sql file into the Database;

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

with this command i am not sure so i have also tried this:

```
mysql -u -p 'USER_name'@'localhost' DB_name < /FULL_PATH/file.sql
```

I still got the syntax error (ERROR 1064) and even i changed the sql file name to avoid _ underscores that might throw errors.

Am i doing something wrong or am i missing something? thanks for the help.

PS: do i have to put the user as: 'USER_name'@'localhost' with single quotes? and include the @localhost?

Comment: any "syntax error near.." or something like that? can you please post the sql file?

Comment: no, but thanks for your answer.